# Rounding values to 2 digits and excluding NA in calculations

Tags: r, rounding, na, confidence-interval

I want to run a table 1 function in R that excludes missing values in the calculations and also rounds the digits to 1 decimal place.

This is my code which excludes the NA in the calculations but I don't know how to round to 1 decimal place.

```
table1(~.|adulttab$Sex.x, data=adulttab[-1],render.categorical ="FREQ (PCTnoNA%)",
   render.continuous=c(.="Mean [SD]",.="Median [Q25, Q75]",.="Min, Max"))
```

Also is there a way to include confidence intervals in the table1?

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(adulttab)` as part of your question so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you say "is there a way to include confidence intervals" do you mean a 95% CI for the mean? Or something else? What confidence interval exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
rndr.cont <- function(x, ...) {
    s  <- lapply(stats.default(x, ...), round_pad, digits=1)
    CI <- round_pad(t.test(x)$conf.int, digits=1)
    with(s, c("", 
            "Mean [SD]"         = sprintf("%s [%s]",     MEAN, SD),
            "95% CI"            = sprintf("(%s, %s)",    CI[1], CI[2]),
            "Median [Q25, Q75]" = sprintf("%s [%s, %s]", MEDIAN, q25, q75),
            "Min, Max"          = sprintf("%s, %s",      MIN, MAX)
    ))
}

table1(~.|adulttab$Sex.x, data=adulttab[-1],render.categorical ="FREQ (PCTnoNA%)",
   render.continuous=rndr.cont)
```